# Finding the negation of a formula in CNF that is also in CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I want to find the negation of a CNF expression which is also in CNF form.

How do I do that? Do I do the negation into DNF and then convert that DNF to CNF?

Comment: Do a bunch of DeMorgan's, Double Negations, and Distributions.  And yes, the DeMorgans and Double Negations will get it into DNF, and the Distributions will get it into CNF. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a bunch of DeMorgan's, Double Negations, and Distributions.

The DeMorgans and Double Negations will get it into DNF.

The Distributions will get it into CNF.

Example:

CNF formula:

$$(A \lor \neg B) \land (\neg C \lor D)$$

Negated:

$$\neg((A \lor \neg B) \land (\neg C \lor D))$$

DeMorgans:

$$\neg (A \lor \neg B) \lor \neg (\neg C \lor D))$$

More DeMorgans:

$$(\neg A \land \neg \neg B) \lor (\neg \neg C \land \neg D))$$

Double Negations:

$$(\neg A \land B) \lor (C \land \neg D))$$ (now it is in DNF)

Distribution:

$$((\neg A \land B) \lor C) \land ((\neg A \land B) \lor \neg D))$$

More Distributions:

$$(\neg A \lor C) \land (B \lor C) \land (\neg A \lor \neg D) \land (B \lor \neg D)$$

CNF!

Comment: Is there a specific rule that I can use to generalize this into every possible length of each clause (a clause can also be only one literal)?

Comment: @jimogios  The DeMorgan and Distribution rules can be generalized, e.g. $\neg (A \land B \land C) = \neg A \lor \neg B \lor \neg C)$ (so it works with any number  of conjuncts and disjuncts),   and for Distribution you can have things like: $(A \land B \land C) \lor (D \land E \land F) = (A \lor D) \land (A \lor E) \land (A \lor F) \land (B \lor D) \land (B \lor E) \land (B \lor F) \land (C \lor D) \land (C \lor E) \land (C \lor F)$ .. and that likewise generalizes for any number of conjuncts and disjuncts

Comment: so if we have k clauses in the initial CNF, we will have clauses of k literals each at the finished negated CNF? e.g. given $(A∨¬B)∧(¬C∨D)∧(¬E∨F)$ we would have clauses of 3 literals each like this: $(¬A∨C∨E)∧(¬A∨C∨¬F)∧...$?

Comment: @jimogios yes, that's exactly right!  And if these $k$ Original clauses contain $n_1, n_2, ... , n_k$ literals each, then you will end up with $n_1 \cdot n_2 \cdot ... \cdot n_k$ clauses each containing $k$ literals. ... although some clauses may disappear when you simplify further.